# What differences do people notice about career changers Vs 'native' CS/softw engr pros in terms of abilities related to work?

Tags: career-development, careers, career-switch, transition

I would like to start a career in CS/software engineering; my background is in math and finance.

Comment: Welcome to The Workplace!  Your question is depends very much on the person and the employer, and as such is likely to be closed as off-topic for being opinion-based.

Comment: Related: [What are the ways to get into a field without a degree in that field?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/70246) and [Writing a resume when shifting focus](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/52295)

Answer (score 2):

They will notice your education in your CV is not computer science related.

Answer (score -3):

Software is like being a rock guitarist.  (Think: Joe Walsh!)

Software is all of

- incredibly well paid
- incredibly hard to "break in"
- you have to spend an awful long time "at the bottom" before you "break in"

and relevant to you

- nobody really cares much about qualifications or background

Far and away, software is the field where (bizarrely, really) you can get away with having oddball / lacking / none background or qualifications.

**That's *if* you're Joe Walsh.**

If anything, degrees in "math and finance" are fantastic.

I see it as a positive, if anything.

But the reality items you (and everyone dreaming of the Wonders of writing software for a living) face are these two:

- incredibly hard to "break in"
- you have to spend an awful long time "at the bottom" before you "break in"

Comment: Well, I feel that design (I lean toward more abstract 'things') is a missing element from my current job, which places heavy emphases on analysis and communication.